# Compare tables in two DB schemas - SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, linq, sql-server-2008, compare, schema

Here is modified question as reply to Alireza:

a) dtResult is only an interim table. I intended to use another DataTable whose structure is as shown below in (c)

b) If an item (table / column) is missing in one of source or target, that item will be poopulated only in that category. E.g. if a new table is added in source, in DataTable, all source-related cols will be NULL (blank) and target-related columns will have data.

c) Sorry for misleading. As said in a) above, dtResult is only an interim table.
The code after that is as below (though, I know, it is all messy!)

var tables = dtResult.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(a => a[0],b=>b[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID3uc.jpg)).OrderBy(b=>b.Key)  ;//.Select(lst => new { table = lst.Key, Count = lst.Count() });

```
        dtResultClone = new DataTable(); 
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TableName"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SourceColName"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SourceColNo"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SourceColDefault"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SourceIsNullable"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SourceDataType"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SourceMaxLen"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TargetColName"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TargetColNo"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TargetColDefault"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TargetIsNullable"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TargetDataType"));
        dtResultClone.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TargetMaxLen"));      

foreach (var tbl in tables)
            {


            string sel = "TableName='" + tbl.Key.ToString() + "'";

            DataRow[] d1 = dtResult.Select(sel);

            foreach (var d2 in d1)
            {
                drc = dtResultClone.NewRow();
                drc[0] = tbl.Key.ToString();

                if (d2["Difference"].ToString().Contains("Target"))
                {
                    drc["TargetColName"] = d2["ColName"].ToString();
                    drc["TargetColNo"] = d2["ColNo"].ToString();
                    drc["TargetColDefault"] = d2["ColDefault"].ToString();
                    drc["TargetIsNullable"] = d2["IsNullable"].ToString();
                    drc["TargetDataType"] = d2["DataType"].ToString();
                    drc["TargetMaxLen"] = d2["MaxLen"].ToString(); 

                }
                else
                {
                    drc["SourceColName"] = d2["ColName"].ToString();
                    drc["SourceColNo"] = d2["ColNo"].ToString();
                    drc["SourceColDefault"] = d2["ColDefault"].ToString();
                    drc["SourceIsNullable"] = d2["IsNullable"].ToString();
                    drc["SourceDataType"] = d2["DataType"].ToString();
                    drc["SourceMaxLen"] = d2["MaxLen"].ToString(); 

                }

                dtResultClone.Rows.Add(drc);
                drc = null;  
            }



        }
```

I am writing a .NET Winforms application, which takes server / db details and compares the tables and shows the diff in a datagridview.

Currently, I am getting the details using a SQL query and store results in two DataTables (one for source, another for target).

I am using LINQ to 'except' these two datatables the result of which I am binding to grid.

My requirement is to show results like below:

[image]

However, currently the grid is displaying results like this:

[image]

Code snippet:

```
var MissingInTarget = qry1.Except(qry2); var MissingInSource = qry2.Except(qry1);

if (MissingInTarget.Any())
            {
                foreach (var id in MissingInTarget)
                {
                    dr = dtResult.NewRow();
                    dr[0] = id.Table;
                    dr[1] = id.Column;
                    dr[2] = id.ColNo;
                    dr[3] = id.ColDefault;
                    dr[4] = id.IsNullable;
                    dr[5] = id.DataType;
                    dr[6] = id.MaxLen;                   

                    dr[7] = "In Source";
                    dtResult.Rows.Add(dr); }


            }
```

....

Any help would be greatly acknowledged!

Comment: This question is a mess, sorry, can't put it any better. Remember that people will not first read a comment (even deleted now) and then your question.

Comment: Agree. And I solved the issue using 'traditional' way of comparing each datarow of tables.